# Как правильно реализовать наследование Java?

Tags: java, ооп, классы, наследование, интерфейс

Вопрос кажется несложным, но я не могу найти на него ответ. Есть интерфейс `Parent`, который объявляет метод `parentMethod`:

```
public interface Parent { 
    public void parentMethod(Argument arg);
}
```

Есть интерфейс `Child`, который наследуется от `Parent` и объявляет ещё метод `childMethod`:

```
public interface Child { 
    public void childMethod(Argument arg);
}
```

Я хочу создать абстрактные классы списков `Child` и `Parent`.

```
public abstract class ParentList {
    public List<Parent> elements;
    public ParentList(List<Parent> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }
    public parentMethodAll (Argument arg) {
        for (Parent element : elements) {
            element.parentMethod(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Класс списка `ChildList` делает всё то же, что и `ParentList` + метод `childMethodAll`, значит `ChildList` может быть наследован от `ParentList`:

```
public abstract class ChildList extends ParentList {
    public ChildList(List<Child> elements) {
        super(elements);
    }
    public childMethodAll (Argument arg) {
        for (Child element : super.elements) {
            element.childMethod(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Но это не работает, потому что невозможно преобразовать `List<Child>` в `List<Parent>`. И даже если бы возможно было это сделать, у элементов `List<Parent>` нет метода `childMethod(arg)`. Как тогда можно реализовать это наследование? Я понимаю, что можно сделать это и без наследования. Но в общем случае, если есть большой класс, который использует `Parent` и мы хотим из него получить класс, который делает то же самое, но использует `Child` вместо `Parent` + реализует метод, основанный на том, что есть у `Child`, но нет у `Parent`. Как это сделать?

Comment: List<? extends Parent> будет достаточно, если я ничего не спутал (во все методы, где есть список)

Comment: а зачем в ChildList  методы ParentList? это вообще уже не ООП

Comment: А какова конечная задача?
Что должен возвращать метод childMethodAll в классе ChildList?

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего хотелось бы заметить, что в показанном коде интерфейс `Child` никак не связан с интерфейсом `Parent`, для наследования код должен быть исправлен.  Также может понадобиться типизировать данные классы по типу аргумента `A`

```java
interface Parent<A> {
    void parentMethod(A arg);
}

interface Child<A> extends Parent<A> {
    void childMethod(A arg);
}
```

По сути вопроса, иерархия `ParentList -> ChildList` не нужна, также непонятна причина, по которой эти классы являются абстрактными.

Достаточно было бы создать обобщённый класс-контейнер, и в нём реализовать метод, вызывающий некую функцию `BiConsumer` для всех элементов контейнера:

```java
public class MyList<A, P extends Parent<A>> {
    private List<P> list;
    
    public MyList(List<P> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    
    public void applyAll(BiConsumer<P, A> fun, A arg) {
        list.forEach(p -> fun.accept(p, arg));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Может вам надо ChildList поправить?

```
public abstract class ChildList extends ParentList {
    //Добавляем детей
    public List<Child> childElements;

    public ChildList(List<Parent> parentElements, List<Child> childElements) {
        this.childElements = childElements;
        super(parentElements);
    }
    public childMethodAll (Argument arg) {
        //Перебираем детей
        for (Child element : this.childElements) {
            element.childMethod(arg);
        }
    }
}
```